# KeyError in JSON request Python - NYT API

Tags: python

I am trying to extract the URL of specific articles from NYT API. 
This is my code:

```
import requests

for i in range(0,100):
    page=str(i)
    r = requests.get("http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?begin_date=20100101&q=terrorist+attack&page="+page+"&api-key=***")
    data = r.json()
    article = data['response']['docs']   
    for url in article:
        print(url["web_url"])
```

After printing the first 20 URL it gives me this error

```
KeyError: 'response'
```

however by checking random pages the key 'response' is present in any of them. What can I do to print all the URLs from the next 88 pages?

Comment: Try to print out the value of data. Do you see a key with the name `response`?

Comment: The key "response" is in any page of the query. If I print the url from any single page I get the proper data. However I want to use a loop for it

Comment: This is the JSON structure: {
  "response": {
    "meta": {
      "hits": 28996,
      "time": 247,
      "offset": 30
    },
    "docs": [
      {
        "web_url": "http://www.nytimes.com/2010/07/25/opinion/25hartley.html",

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem. You might be requesting faster than the allowed limit of 5 per second. In that case, the NYT server is going to hit you with an error message, so there will be no 'response' key. I would suggest printing out the keys from every GET request using something like:

```
print(dict.keys(data))
```

If you keep seeing 'message' as one of your keys, then you know that you're probably requesting too fast. So just put in a `time.sleep(0.5)` to slow things down and you should be good.

Comment: I tried dict.keys(data) on NYT and got a dict_keys(['message']) and dict_keys(['status', 'copyright', 'response']) and then the KeyError. So I didn't see multiple 'message's. Yet I tried time.sleep and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that there are at least 101 pages to make requests (0 to 100).

If you make a request to page 100, do you still get the same JSON structure with a `response` key?

What you should instead use is a while loop that breaks when you get a `KeyError`.